# Spark MySQL write error Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D' for column at row 1

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, encoding

I have a MySQL table with columns created with columns like-> `POST` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,so on

And am writing to mysql table from Spark using scala

```
DF.write.mode("append").jdbc(jdbcUrl,"feeds",connectionProperties)
```

My jdfc url is ,

```
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:mysql://${jdbcHostname},useUnicode=true&charset=utf8mb4"
```

I have also changed below properties by referring to https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/04/10/migrating-database-charsets-to-utf8mb4/

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And still no luck I am getting same error while writing to mysql table,

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: (conn=35650) Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D' for column 'any' at row 1

(from comment)

```
CREATE TABLE feeds_v2 (
    EMAIL varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    POST_MESSAGE longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, 
    POST longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, 
    message_tags_name varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    COMMENT_MESSAGE longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, 
    COMMENT_FROM_ID varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
    COMMENT_NAME varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález but i have no issue with jdbc connection

Comment: characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: And, let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames CREATE TABLE `feeds_v2` (
  `EMAIL` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_MESSAGE` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `POST` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `message_tags_name` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENT_MESSAGE` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `COMMENT_FROM_ID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENT_NAME` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin

Comment: Let's see the url now.

Comment: @RickJames This is how I am forming val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:mysql://${jdbcHostname},useUnicode=true&charset=utf8mb4"

Comment: That still does not have `characterEncoding=UTF-8`.  I _think_ that is independent of MySQL's charset.

Comment: @RickJames I added characterEncoding=UTF-8 but still it didn't work